# How to calculate the $p$-torsion points of an elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

How to calculate the $p$-torsion points of an elliptic curve?

Consider the elliptic curve $E: \ y^2=x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then it is given that $E[2]=\{0,~(\sqrt[3]{5},0),~(\zeta_2 \sqrt[3]{5},0),~(\zeta_3^2 \sqrt[3]{5},0) \}$. see for instance Page $2$ [here](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/galois_representations_study_group.pdf)

Clearly these points satisfy the elliptic curve though they do not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$.

But I didn't see how these are $2$-torsion points.

Can you help me to explain?

If $P=(x,y)$ be a $2$-torsion point of $E: \ y^2=x^3-5$, then $2P=0$.

Also, What are the $3$-torsion points ?

Do Pari/gp  calculate torsion points ?

Comment: The non-zero three torsion points on this curve are given by $(0, \pm \sqrt{-5})$ and $(\zeta_3^i\sqrt[3]{20}, \pm\sqrt{15})$. You can definitely compute this using Pari/gp, Sage, Magma etc.

Comment: @Mathmo123, Can you leave it as answer showing the calculation, please ? I need to understand the calculation.

Comment: For the first pair of points, you can use the fact that $\mathrm{div}(y \pm \sqrt{-5}) = 2(0, \pm\sqrt{-5})-2\infty$ (because $(y-\sqrt{-5})(y+\sqrt{-5}) = x^3$). For the second set, you can use the $3$-torsion polynomial (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials)), which gives you the $x$-coordinate of all the $3$-torsion points. There's probably an explicit way to see it as a divisor.

Comment: I would start with Nagell Lutz: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted by @Somos, but denied by @hunter, finding $3$-torsion points is easy. Consider the following sequence of logical equivalences, in which I use $T_EP$ to mean the tangent line to the elliptic curve at $P$, and I call the point at infinity $\Bbb O$:
\begin{align}
P\text{ is $3$-torsion}&\Leftrightarrow[3](P)=\Bbb O\\
&\Leftrightarrow[2](P)=-P\\
&\Leftrightarrow T_EP\text{ has its third intersection with $E$ at the point symmetric to $-P$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow T_EP\text{ has its third intersection with $E$ at $P$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow T_EP\text{ makes $3$-fold contact with $E$ at $P$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\text{ $P$ is an inflection point of $E$ .}
\end{align}
Note that this accords with the well-known fact that the point at infinity is an inflection point of $E$ .

Comment: Thank very much sir

Comment: I just saw this! Sadly my year-old comment is uneditable, but your answer is at the top now.

Answer (score 5):

By definition of the group law, in Weierstrass form, a $2$-torsion point is a point where the graph has a vertical tangent.  This is equivalent to the $y$-coordinate being zero (by the symmetry about the $x$-axis).

Comment: Thanks. Can you further help me with $3$-torsion points ?

Comment: @mathvision that's harder! You can google for explicit formulas but there is no nice principle. (And yes, using a CAS like Pari to calculate them makes sense.)

Answer (score 3):

The LMFDB is very useful for these kind of questions. In particular, the
[Elliptic curve 10800.be1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/10800/bq/1)
defined by $\,y^2 = x^3-5\,$ is the one you asked about. At the bottom of
the web page is a section "Growth of torsion in number fields" The first
entry is the curve over $\,K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})\,$ with the torsion
group listed as $\,\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\,$ which implies that there is
a $3$-torsion point. We guess that such a point is $\,P=(0,\sqrt{-5})\,$
and in fact $\,-P=P+P=(0,-\sqrt{-5}).\,$ You can do the simple
calculations with [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr):

```
al = Mod(x, x^4+5); /* al^4 = -5 */
E = ellinit([0,0,0,0,al^2]); /* y^2 = x^3-5 */
P = [0,al]; /* (0,sqrt(-5)) */
ellisoncurve(E, P) /* ==1 True */
-P == ellmul(E, P, 2) /* ==1 True 2*P = (0,-sqrt(-5)) */
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Did you check the code ?  I tried this code in PARI/GP. But not giving output

Comment: @mathvision Yes, I just checked it. The last two lines should each return $1$.